Multiple regression correlated predictors
I am trying to fit a multiple regression model with several predictors. Here you can find a reproducible example.
require("MASS")
require ("psych")
library("data.table")


set.seed(123)

cov.matone <- matrix(c(1, .1, .3,
                       .1, 1,.2,
                       .3,.2,1), nrow = 3)

dfone <- data.frame(MASS::mvrnorm(n = 1e3, 
                                  mu = c(0, 0, 0), 
                                  Sigma = cov.matone))
cor(dfone)

M1 <-  lm(X1 ~ X2, data = dfone, na.action="na.exclude")
summary(M1)

M2 <-  lm(X1 ~ X2+X3, data = dfone, na.action="na.exclude")
summary(M2)

The problem is that some of these predictors are correlated due to methodological problems. Imagine that X2 is temperature and X3 is age. I want to include age as a covariate but it is correlated with temperature since older people were collected during summer whereas younger people during winter. Imagine that X1 is criminal behavior which is influenced by temperature and also age. However, temperature becomes non-significant once I include age into the model—although it has a clear effect.
I have tried partial correlations and working with the residuals but I get the same non-significant result. I have also thought about using principal component regression but If I do that there is no way to test if temperature is a significant predictor (controlling for age). I only can calculate the increment of the variance explained once I add temperature into the model.
Is there any wat to tackle this issue? Thank you so much in advance.
PS: I have checked similar post but I have not found any solution for this specific issue.

Unfortunately, the short answer is no.  The point of multicollinearity is that when two variables are strongly correlated, you have little information with which to differentiate them.  As a result, it may be clear that there is an effect associated with at least one of them (i.e., you can do a simultaneous test of both), but you lack the required information to determine which is responsible.  You are stuck with that.
More generally, power can be improved by gathering more data, gathering uncorrelated data, and/or including other (uncorrelated, but relevant) variables that will reduce the error variance.  You could also try a Bayesian analysis.

Thak you so much for your response @gung. I have tried a Bayesian Regression but it is also non-significant.

A generic Bayesian analysis is unlikely to improve things much, @JuanJMV, you would need strong priors.  The Bayesian analysis would be better if you were incorporating a lot of high quality information from other sources.  Consider that you can get a significant result from a standard analysis with enough additional data--that's adding more information.  A Bayesian analysis would work by giving you a different method to add a lot more information, but only if you had it.
